# Trying to find unique subarrays and sub-elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, nested-lists

I have an array will subarrays containing [page_name, url, and id] in dirty_pages. This array contain duplicate subarrays.

I need to parse each `subarray` in `dirty_pages` into `clean_pages` such that:

1. there are no duplicates (repeating subarray)
2. the `1st index` in the subarray *i.e. the url must be unique!* For example This url should be counted as **one** *(`url/#review` is still the same url)*:

   ```
   file:///home/joe/Desktop/my-projects/FashionShop/product.html#review
   ```

   and

   ```
   file:///home/joe/Desktop/my-projects/FashionShop/product.html
   ```

My current attempt returns `clean_pages` with 6 subarrays (duplicates!) while the correct answer should be 4

```
# clean pages
clean_pages = []


# dirty pages
dirty_pages = [
  ['Fashion Shop | Free Bootstrap Themes by 365Bootstrap.com', 'file:///home/joe/Desktop/my-projects/FashionShop/index.html', '1608093980462.042'],
  ['Put a Sock in It Heel Boot | Nasty Gal', 'file:///home/joe/Desktop/my-projects/FashionShop/nastygal-product.html', '1608093980462.042'],
  ['Fashion Shop | Free Bootstrap Themes by 365Bootstrap.com', 'file:///home/joe/Desktop/my-projects/FashionShop/index.html', '1608093980462.042'],
  ['Fashion Shop | Free Bootstrap Themes by 365Bootstrap.com', 'file:///home/joe/Desktop/my-projects/FashionShop/index.html', '1608093980462.042'],
  ['Fashion Shop | Free Bootstrap Themes by 365Bootstrap.com', 'file:///home/joe/Desktop/my-projects/FashionShop/product.html', '1608093980462.042'],
  ['Fashion Shop | Free Bootstrap Themes by 365Bootstrap.com', 'file:///home/joe/Desktop/my-projects/FashionShop/product.html#review', '1608093980462.042'],
  ['Fashion Shop | Free Bootstrap Themes by 365Bootstrap.com', 'file:///home/joe/Desktop/my-projects/FashionShop/product.html#review', '1608093980462.042'],
  ['Fashion Shop | Free Bootstrap Themes by 365Bootstrap.com', 'file:///home/joe/Desktop/my-projects/FashionShop/index.html', '1608093980462.042'],
  ['Put a Sock in It Heel Boot | Nasty Gal', 'file:///home/joe/Desktop/my-projects/FashionShop/nastygal-product.html', '1608093980462.042'],
  ['ICONIC EXCLUSIVE - Game Over Drop Crotch Track Pants - Kids by Rock Your Kid Online | THE ICONIC | Australia', 'file:///home/joe/Desktop/my-projects/FashionShop/iconic-product.html', '1608093980462.042'],
   ['Put a Sock in It Heel Boot | Nasty Gal', 'file:///home/joe/Desktop/my-projects/FashionShop/nastygal-product.html', '1608093980462.042'],
  ['Fashion Shop | Free Bootstrap Themes by 365Bootstrap.com', 'file:///home/shahyan/Desktop/my-projects/FashionShop/index.html/#review', '1608093980462.042'],
  ['Fashion Shop | Free Bootstrap Themes by 365Bootstrap.com', 'file:///home/shahyan/Desktop/my-projects/FashionShop/index.html/?123', '1608093980462.042'],
  ['Fashion Shop | Free Bootstrap Themes by 365Bootstrap.com', 'file:///home/shahyan/Desktop/my-projects/FashionShop/index.html/', '1608093980462.042'],
    ]




# clean data - get unique pages for each session
for j in range(len(dirty_pages)):
    page_name = dirty_pages[j][0]
    page_url = dirty_pages[j][1]
    page_sessionId = dirty_pages[j][2]

    not_seen = False

    if len(clean_pages) == 0:
        clean_pages.append([page_name, page_url, page_sessionId])
    else:
        for i in range(len(clean_pages)):
            next_page_name = clean_pages[i][0]
            next_page_url = clean_pages[i][1]
            next_page_sessionId = clean_pages[i][2]

            if page_url != next_page_url and page_name != next_page_name \
                    and page_sessionId == next_page_sessionId:
                not_seen = True
            else:
                not_seen = False

    if not_seen is True:
        clean_pages.append([page_name, page_url, page_sessionId])

print("$$$ clean...", len(clean_pages))

# correct answer should be 4 - as anyting after url e.g. #review is still duplicate!
```

**UPDATE EXAMPLE - Apologies if example wasn't clear (just like # after url these should be considered one url)**

```
'file:///home/joe/Desktop/my-projects/FashionShop/index.html/'

'file:///home/joe/Desktop/my-projects/FashionShop/index.html/?123'

'file:///home/joe/Desktop/my-projects/FashionShop/index.html'
```

Comment: Suggestion: 1) Write a function `clean_url` which takes a url and outputs a standard form for that url (for instance removing `#review`) 2) Use a python `set` to store your urls, so duplicates are automatically taken care of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [furl](https://github.com/gruns/furl) for normalizing the urls

```py
from furl import furl

# Iterate over each page - subarray
for page in dirty_pages:
    # normalize url
    page[1] = furl(page[1]).remove(args=True, fragment=True).url.strip("/")

    # check if subarray already in clean_pages
    if page not in clean_pages:
        clean_pages.append(page)
```

Comment: This is partially correct, #review after url was as example, your answer duplicates url with  / at the end e.g.  '.../index.html/' and '../index.html/?123' and '../index.html' is also still the same url. Please see example in the question (just to be clear)

Comment: Updated answer to handle cases as in the new example.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
for j in dirty_pages:
    page_name = j[0]
    long_url = j[1]
    split_url = long_url.split('#')
    short_url = split_url[0]
    page_sessionID = j[2]
    edited_subarray = [page_name, short_url, page_sessionID]
    if edited_subarray not in clean_pages:
        clean_pages.append(edited_subarray)
```

Unless you need to preserve the "#review" part of the url in your clean_pages list.

Comment: You might want to display a warning if `'/' in split_url[1]`

Comment: Please check the update example in question. the url still duplicates if there is something else after the / i.e. '../index.html/?123' and '.../index.html/#review' should be counted as unique

Comment: My only other thought would be to to split on ('.html') instead of ('#').

Answer (score 0):

I think in essence this problem boils down to there being a unique url. If so the previous way you were checking is a bit overcomplicated and the results you were getting came down to just adding the first item of the unique name. Hence the 6 however it seems you want the unique url.

To get over the # problem I just split the url around the hashtag and took the first part of it. Note this will only get the first part of the string before the hashtag. So this could cause issues if there is more than 1 #.

I have also cleaned it up a bit

```
    # clean pages
clean_pages = []


# dirty pages
dirty_pages = [
  ['Fashion Shop | Free Bootstrap Themes by 365Bootstrap.com', 'file:///home/joe/Desktop/my-projects/FashionShop/index.html', '1608093980462.042'],
  ['Put a Sock in It Heel Boot | Nasty Gal', 'file:///home/joe/Desktop/my-projects/FashionShop/nastygal-product.html', '1608093980462.042'],
  ['Fashion Shop | Free Bootstrap Themes by 365Bootstrap.com', 'file:///home/joe/Desktop/my-projects/FashionShop/index.html', '1608093980462.042'],
  ['Fashion Shop | Free Bootstrap Themes by 365Bootstrap.com', 'file:///home/joe/Desktop/my-projects/FashionShop/index.html', '1608093980462.042'],
  ['Fashion Shop | Free Bootstrap Themes by 365Bootstrap.com', 'file:///home/joe/Desktop/my-projects/FashionShop/product.html', '1608093980462.042'],
  ['Fashion Shop | Free Bootstrap Themes by 365Bootstrap.com', 'file:///home/joe/Desktop/my-projects/FashionShop/product.html#review', '1608093980462.042'],
  ['Fashion Shop | Free Bootstrap Themes by 365Bootstrap.com', 'file:///home/joe/Desktop/my-projects/FashionShop/product.html#review', '1608093980462.042'],
  ['Fashion Shop | Free Bootstrap Themes by 365Bootstrap.com', 'file:///home/joe/Desktop/my-projects/FashionShop/index.html', '1608093980462.042'],
  ['Put a Sock in It Heel Boot | Nasty Gal', 'file:///home/joe/Desktop/my-projects/FashionShop/nastygal-product.html', '1608093980462.042'],
  ['ICONIC EXCLUSIVE - Game Over Drop Crotch Track Pants - Kids by Rock Your Kid Online | THE ICONIC | Australia', 'file:///home/joe/Desktop/my-projects/FashionShop/iconic-product.html', '1608093980462.042'],
   ['Put a Sock in It Heel Boot | Nasty Gal', 'file:///home/joe/Desktop/my-projects/FashionShop/nastygal-product.html', '1608093980462.042'],
]


used_url = []
used_names = []

# clean data - get unique pages for each session
for page in dirty_pages:
    page_name = page[0]
    page_url = page[1].split('#')[0]
    page_sessionId = page[2]

    if page_url not in used_url:
        used_url.append(page_url)
        clean_pages.append(page)

print(clean_pages)
print("$$$ clean...", len(clean_pages))
```

Comment: Please check the update example in question. the url still duplicates if there is something else after the / i.e. '../index.html/?123'  and '.../index.html/#review' should  be counted as unique